Mutation Observer - Chrome extension
I am developing an extension for Chrome as part of a final year project in cybersecurity. This extension aims to scan websites and detect potential vulnerabilities. This project is carried out in Vue.JS3 On the client side I try to read the DOM to detect possible modifications. We use Observer mutations
So for those in the know, we have:

An Options part
A DevTools part
A Popup part
A contentScripts part

We launch an Observer mutation in the content script in order to retrieve the DOM of the site where the user is located, except for certain sites, the extension retrieves its own DOM and I don't understand why.
For example here on https://test.fr the mutation works well.
https://i.sstatic.net/yWPpkA0w.png
But here on a site created to detect a DOM XSS done manually it doesn't work. https://i.sstatic.net/DdtN3Vl4.png

import {
    createApp
} from 'vue';
import App from './views/App.vue';
import {
    setupApp
} from '~/logic/common-setup';
import store from '~/store';

(() => {
    var _a;

    const initialize = () => {
        console.log("Initializing...");

        const observer = new MutationObserver(async (mutationsList) => {
            try {
                console.log("Running observer");
                for (let mutation of mutationsList) {
                    switch (mutation.type) {
                        case 'childList':
                            for (let node of mutation.addedNodes) {
                                if (node.tagName === 'SCRIPT' && node.src.startsWith('moz-extension://')) {
                                    return;
                                }
                                // if (node.parentNode && node.parentNode.shadowRoot && node.parentNode.id === 'app-container') {
                                //     continue;
                                // }
                                if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE && !node.data.trim()) {
                                    return;
                                }
                                await handleNodeAdded(node);
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'attributes':
                            await handleAttributeModified(mutation.target, mutation.attributeName);
                            break;
                        case 'characterData':
                            if (mutation.target.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE && !mutation.target.data.trim()) {
                                return;
                            }
                            await handleCharacterDataModified(mutation.target);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error in observer:', error);
            }
        });

        observer.observe(document.documentElement, {
            childList: true,
            subtree: true,
            attributes: true,
            characterData: true
        });

        const container = document.createElement('div');
        container.id = 'app-container';
        const root = document.createElement('div');
        const styleEl = document.createElement('link');
        const shadowDOM = ((_a = container.attachShadow) === null || _a === void 0 ? void 0 : _a.call(container, {
            mode: 'open'
        })) || container;
        styleEl.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
        styleEl.setAttribute('href', browser.runtime.getURL('dist/contentScripts/style.css'));
        shadowDOM.appendChild(styleEl);
        shadowDOM.appendChild(root);
        document.body.appendChild(container);
        const app = createApp(App);

        app.use(store);
        setupApp(app);
        app.mount(root);

        store.dispatch('initializeAuthState');

        chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message) => {
            console.log('Content Script: Message received:', message);
            if (message.action === 'setAuthState') {
                store.commit('setAuthState', message.payload);
            } else if (message.action === 'clearAuthState') {
                store.commit('clearAuthState');
            }
        });

        console.info('[WebPionneer] Content script initialized!');
    };

    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', initialize);
    window.addEventListener('load', initialize);

    const startPolling = () => {
        setInterval(() => {
            console.log('Polling for changes...');
            document.querySelectorAll('your-selector-here').forEach(node => {
                handleNodeAdded(node);
            });
        }, 2000);
    };

    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', startPolling);
    window.addEventListener('load', startPolling);

    async function handleNodeAdded(node) {
        console.log('Node added:', node);
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
        console.log('Async operation for added node completed');
    }

    async function handleAttributeModified(target, attributeName) {
        console.log('Attribute modified:', target, 'Attribute name:', attributeName);
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
        console.log('Async operation for attribute modification completed');
    }

    async function handleCharacterDataModified(target) {
        console.log('Character data modified:', target);
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
        console.log('Async operation for character data modification completed');
    }
})();


Thanks to anyone who can give me an answer 
